# PostgreSQL - how to sum only positive cumulative sums in total

Tags: postgresql

I try to write a select query in my PostgreSQL database table containing history of customers settlement. The query result should show sum of amounts based only of customers, who are debtors (sum of all invoices amounts of each customer is gteater than zero). 
 In attached example (picture below) - when we take detailed settlement history from date: 10.06.2021,  You can see that invoices total amount of customer A is plus (+) 190000 so this customers sum should be taken to total sum. From the other side, invoices amount sum of customer B is minus (-)266000 so this one is not debtor and should be skipped. I try to make a sum containing only positive partial sums of each customer divided by customer status as shown on the screen below (Expected result).

[image]

I tried query like this:

```
    select s.*, s.active+s.inactive total from
(select to_char(date_trunc('month', debt_date),'YYYY-MM'),
       greatest(sum(case when t.status = 'Active' then t.amount::numeric else 0 end),0) active,
       greatest(sum(case when t.status = 'Inactive' then t.amount::numeric else 0 end),0) inactive       
  from customers_settlement t
 group by 1) s  order by 1;
```

but it didn't work - manual calculation in Excel gave different results than the query. I guess that there is something missing like:

```
over (partition by customer)
```

I believe that professionals like You, will be able to help me quickly. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally certain if that is what you want, but you could first group by month and customer, then eliminate negative results, then sum again:

```
SELECT m,
       sum(active) AS "sum(Active)",
       sum(inactive) AS "sum(Inactive)",
       sum(active) + sum(inactive) AS "sum(Total)"
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', debt_date),'YYYY-MM') AS m,
             greatest(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE t.status = 'Active'), 0) AS active,
             greatest(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE t.status = 'Inactive'), 0) AS inactive
      FROM customers_settlement AS t
      GROUP BY m, customer) AS subq
GROUP BY m;
```

Comment: You are the master! It works perfectly! Thank You for help so much!